# regex to set the group length in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a version 'major.minor.patch'
major version range `[0-99999]`
minor version range `[0-9999]`
patch version range `[0-999999]`
but on the whole 'major.minor.path' should not exceed 16 characters including . (dot).
I have tried the following reg expression

```
^(\d{1,5}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,6}){1,16}$
```

but {1,16} means 1 to 16 repetitions of previous expression not the length of previous group
How can I make the length of following group to 16

```
(\d{1,5}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,6})
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this to be a single regex? It would be simpler to have your regex be `(\d+)[.](\d+)[.](\d+)` and then make the rests of the checks separately (see if version ranges are correct and if len(thestring) is under the limit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two regular expressions here that you want to combine

1. `^[\d.]{,16}$`
2. `^\d{1,5}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,6}$`

Both in itself is invalid as (1) can match more than 2 dots and the individual length limits on each version are not honoured. (2) definitely does not work as it exceeds the string length limit of 16 characters including '.'

A less known feature of regex lookhead can be used to combine(and-ed) both the above regex expressions which would be something like

```
^(?=[\d.]{,16}$)\d{1,5}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,6}$
```

Example:

```
exp = r'^(?=[\d.]{,16}$)\d{1,5}[.]\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,6}$'
vers = ['111.111.111', 
        '111111.1111.1111', 
        '11111.1111.111111', 
        '11111.1111.11111']
["{} Matches ? {}".format(v, "YES" if re.match(exp, v) else "NO" ) 
 for v in vers]
```

Output

```
['111.111.111 Matches ? YES', 
 '111111.1111.1111 Matches ? NO', 
 '11111.1111.111111 Matches ? NO', 
 '11111.1111.11111 Matches ? YES']
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit   regex look ahead solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a lookahead at the beginning that allows a match only if its within 1-16 range by using a `$` to anchor at the end: `(?=^.{1,16}$)`